# TaskFactory, Starting a new Task when one ends

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, threadpool

I have found many methods of using the `TaskFactory` but I could not find anything about starting more tasks and watching when one ends and starting another one.

I always want to have 10 tasks working.

I want something like this

```
int nTotalTasks=10;
int nCurrentTask=0;

Task<bool>[] tasks=new Task<bool>[nThreadsNum];

for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
  string param1="test";
  string param2="test";

  if (nCurrentTask<10) // if there are less than 10 tasks then start another one
    tasks[nCurrentThread++] = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
    {
       MyClass cls = new MyClass();
       bool bRet = cls.Method1(param1, param2, i); // takes up to 2 minutes to finish
       return bRet;
    });

  // How can I stop the for loop until a new task is finished and start a new one?
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `WaitAny()` method or tried waiting on a `task.Result`?

Comment: Are the tasks IO bound or CPU bound?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Task.WaitAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd270672%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) method:

> Waits for any of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

Example from the documentation:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoOperation1());
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoOperation2());

Task.WaitAny(t1, t2)
```

Comment: and how do I know which task finished?, because I need to know the return value of the finished task

Comment: @MarioM - The same way you would without the `WaitAny` call. `Task.Result`

Comment: @MarioM `WaitAny()` returns index in input array of tasks

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main") and TPL for this. It becomes very simple.

Here's the code:

```
int nTotalTasks=10;
string param1="test";
string param2="test";

IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 1000)
        .Select(i => Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
        {
            MyClass cls = new MyClass();
            bool bRet = cls.Method1(param1, param2, i); // takes up to 2 minutes to finish
            return bRet;
        })))
        .Merge(nTotalTasks)
        .ToArray()
        .Subscribe((bool[] results) =>
        {
            /* Do something with the results. */
        });
```

The key part here is the `.Merge(nTotalTasks)` which limits the number of concurrent tasks.

If you need to stop the processing part way thru just call `subscription.Dispose()` and everything gets cleaned up for you.

If you want to process each result as they are produced you can change the code from the `.Merge(...)` like this:

```
        .Merge(nTotalTasks)
        .Subscribe((bool result) =>
        {
            /* Do something with each result. */
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need, not complete, but all you need to do is wait on the first to complete and then run the second.

```
Task.WaitAny(task to wait on);

Task.Factory.StartNew()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) class? It allows you to have multiple threads running in parallel and you can wait from results from one task to execute another. See more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No, very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether the tasks to be scheduled are CPU or I/O bound.

For CPU-intensive work I would use `Parallel.For()` API setting the number of thread/tasks through `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property of `ParallelOptions`

For I/O bound work the number of concurrently executing tasks can be significantly larger than the number of available CPUs, so the strategy is to rely on async methods as much as possible, which reduces the total number of threads waiting for completion.

> How can I stop the for loop until a new task is finished and start a
>   new one?

The loop can be throttled by using await:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = DoWorkAsync();
        task.Wait();

        // handle  results
        // task.Result;

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }

    async static Task<bool> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        const int NUMBER_OF_SLOTS = 10;

        string param1="test";
        string param2="test";

        var results = new bool[NUMBER_OF_SLOTS]; 

        AsyncWorkScheduler ws = new AsyncWorkScheduler(NUMBER_OF_SLOTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            await ws.ScheduleAsync((slotNumber) => DoWorkAsync(i, slotNumber, param1, param2, results));
        }

        ws.Complete();
        await ws.Completion;
    }

    async static Task DoWorkAsync(int index, int slotNumber, string param1, string param2, bool[] results)
    {
      results[slotNumber] = results[slotNumber} && await Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
      {
          MyClass cls = new MyClass();
          bool bRet = cls.Method1(param1, param2, i); // takes up to 2 minutes to finish
          return bRet;
      }));

    }
```

A helper class `AsyncWorkScheduler` uses TPL.DataFlow components as well as  `Task.WhenAll()`:

```
class AsyncWorkScheduler
{
    public AsyncWorkScheduler(int numberOfSlots)
    {
        m_slots = new Task[numberOfSlots];
        m_availableSlots = new BufferBlock<int>();
        m_errors = new List<Exception>();
        m_tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        m_completionPending = 0;

        // Initial state: all slots are available
        for(int i = 0; i < m_slots.Length; ++i)
        {
            m_slots[i] = Task.FromResult(false);
            m_availableSlots.Post(i);
        }
    }

    public async Task ScheduleAsync(Func<int, Task> action)
    {
        if (Volatile.Read(ref m_completionPending) != 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to schedule new items.");
        }

        // Acquire a slot 
        int slotNumber = await m_availableSlots.ReceiveAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Schedule a new task for a given slot
        var task = action(slotNumber);

        // Store a continuation on the task to handle completion events
        m_slots[slotNumber] = task.ContinueWith(t => HandleCompletedTask(t, slotNumber), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }


    public async void Complete()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_completionPending, 1, 0) != 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Signal the queue's completion
        m_availableSlots.Complete();

        await Task.WhenAll(m_slots).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Set completion
        if (m_errors.Count != 0)
        {
            m_tcs.TrySetException(m_errors);
        }
        else
        {
            m_tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }

    }

    public Task Completion
    {
        get
        {
            return m_tcs.Task;
        }
    }



    void SetFailed(Exception error)
    {
        lock(m_errors)
        {
            m_errors.Add(error);
        }

    }

    void HandleCompletedTask(Task task, int slotNumber)
    {
       if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
       {
           SetFailed(task.Exception);
           return;
       }

       if (Volatile.Read(ref m_completionPending) == 1)
       {
           return;
       }


        // Release a slot
        m_availableSlots.Post(slotNumber);
    }

    int m_completionPending;
    List<Exception> m_errors;
    BufferBlock<int> m_availableSlots;
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> m_tcs;
    Task[] m_slots;

}
```